# Add method .equalsOr() to String class

Tags: java, string

I'm just starting with Java.

I wonder if there's a way to add a method so that any String can call that method, similar to how we have now `string1.equals(string2)` that you could use `string1.equalsOr(string2, string3, string4, string5)`.

I know I can make my own static method, but wonder if I could make it available to any string.

Comment: Not in vanilla Java. But you should be able to with Lobmok.

Comment: Better try Kotlin

Comment: or with AspectJ

Comment: @shmosel I suspect you meant to suggest [*Project Lombok*](https://projectlombok.org) (not Lobmok, typo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check equality of your `string1` to a set of strings `string2, string3, string4, string5`. It's better to use any collection (i.e. `Set` or `List`). For example, if you use

```
 Arrays.asList(string2, string3, string4, string5).contains(string1)
```

it will give you the espected result.

Answer (score 5):

```
string1.equalsOr(string2, string3, string4, string5)
```

can be easily written as *(Java 9+)*

```
Set.of(string2, string3, string4, string5).contains(string1)
```

or *(Java 9+)*

```
List.of(string2, string3, string4, string5).contains(string1)
```

or *(Java 8+)*

```
Stream.of(string2, string3, string4, string5).anyMatch(string1::equals)
```

or *(any Java)*

```
Arrays.asList(string2, string3, string4, string5).contains(string1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more comprehensive but since @dehasi's answer came first (for a few seconds) and he's starting (with less reputation than you), I'm going to accept his. +1 anyways

Comment: @Manuel Be aware that the `Set` version may perform better if you have a lot of strings to compare with (`string2` ... `string999`).

Comment: @Andreas: You'd probably want to build the set once and save it, though. Any benefits of hash-based lookup are going to be overwhelmed by building sets over and over.

Answer (score 2):

In java, you can’t extend the `String` class in the way you want.

This is something that other jvm languages are able to do but under the hood are somehow a static method that accepts a `String` and the parameters.

However, other than a static method, what you can do is to create a class that accepts in construction a `String` and add the method you want to this class. 
In this way you are creating your own type with their own logic on top of the java base ones.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You cannot modify the `String` class in this fashion.

Making it available to any string would be effectively you creating that static method, since the only times you'd ever be able to use this construct is when *you* invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with Java, your desire is to retrofit the "String" class which is pretty close to impossible (You actually might be able to edit the source code of String and recompile the java jars but I'm not sure it would work).

On the other hand you absolutely can with Groovy.  Groovy can use most Java code directly but adds extra abilities like the ability to retrofit new methods into existing classes.  Groovy uses this ability heavily to implement functions like "new File("file").getText()" to get the entire text of a file as a string.

Mostly it's nice because it's so easy to switch back and forth between groovy and java--Once you've configured your build to use groovy you can typically just rename a .java file as .groovy and start using groovy features since groovy understands most java code without change.

PS: This is just what you CAN do, not what you should do unless the idea of adding methods to existing classes really appeals to you.

Comment: I was going to mention Kotlin's ability to open classes here too but since they're just starting with the one language, I figured it'd be best to not bury them with too much...

Comment: No, no, don't adopt a whole new language (Groovy, or Kotlin, or anything else) just because you haven't learnt the Java API yet.  Use one of the options in Andreas' answer or dehasi's answer.

Comment: I love java and have used it forever, but I also integrate some groovy since it's essentially the same language (and pretty much as fast at this point).  However I don't recommend it for a large shared code base, java's enforced simplicity is extremely nice for large teams--it's difficult to do anything tricky that others won't understand... In groovy it's extremely easy to code something really "smart"/tricky (like adding methods to String!) and shoot yourself in the foot--but at any rate other approaches are better, just thought I'd mention it if you were really into modifying "String"

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot change the `String` class. However, Java 8+ you can do something along the lines of

```
Stream.of(foo, foo2, foo3).anyMatch(e -> e.equals(string));
```

To determine if `string` equals any of the parameters passed to `Stream.of()`. This is not as pretty as a simple `equalOr()` method, but it still gets the job done without having to write your own method